# How to sort a String or 2d Multidimensional array?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

Basically I have:

```
String[][] mda = {{"Hello ma", "3"},
                  {"How r u?", "2"},
                  {"i m fine", "5"}};
```

To be precise I want to sort this Array based on it's numeric value, which would look like:

```
"How r u?", "2"
"Hello ma", "3"
"i m fine", "5"
```

Regards <3

Comment: Do you need a String[][] as an output, or just store them somewhere?

Comment: think about introducing a more meaningful data structure instead of a string array. Something like a class containing a `sentence` and some kind of `id` property.

Comment: But do you want sort for the numeric value or the string value ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something as simple as this should do the trick.

```
String[][] mda = {{"Hello ma", "3"},
        {"How r u?", "2"},
        {"i m fine", "5"}};

public void test() {
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(mda));
    Arrays.sort(mda, Comparator.comparing(s -> s[1]));
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(mda));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put these in a [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html). You can order them by keys (your integers), and access their values (the string) in order.

This would look like:

```
Map<Integer, String> myMap = new HashMap<>();
for (String[] tmp : myStrings)
{
    myMap.put(Integer.parseInt(tmp[0]), tmp[1]);
}
```

Comment: A `HashMap` will not sort. Use a `TreeMap` to make it sorted.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon But you can access your elements by key, and I assumed from his example that the integers follow each others. So you can just iterate on your Map.size and map.get your increment, as it'll get the value of the index.

Answer (score 0):

You should use comparator to sort array of particular index

```
 String[][] mda = {{"Hello ma", "3"},
                {"How r u?", "2"},
                {"i m fine", "5"}};
         Arrays.sort(mda, new Comparator<String[]>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(final String[] data1, final String[] data2) {
                    final String value1 = data1[1];
                    final String value2 = data2[1];
                    return value1.compareTo(value2);
                }
            });

            for (final String[] str : mda) {
                System.out.println(str[0] + " " + str[1]);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Arrays.sort(mda, (o1, o2) -> Integer.parseInt(o1[1]) - Integer.parseInt(o2[1]) );

Arrays.stream(mda).forEach(l ->
  {
      System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(l));
  });
```

Or if you like the streams:

```
List<String[]> collect = Arrays.stream(mda)
                               .sorted((o1, o2) -> Integer.parseInt(o1[1]) - Integer.parseInt(o2[1]))
                               .collect(Collectors.toList());

collect.forEach(l ->
  {
      System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(l));
  });
```